# parend div scroller to control child div scrolling activity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to controll child div scrolling with parent div scrollbar

```css
#answerform
{
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.clsHeader
{
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;    
  position: relative;
}
.clsText
{
  height:250px;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;   
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='answerform'>
  <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
  <div class="clsText">
    badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
    badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
    badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
    badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
  </div>
  <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
  <div class="clsText">
    badger
  </div>
  <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
  <div class="clsText">
    badger
  </div>
  <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
  <div class="clsText">
    badger
  </div>   
</div>
```

refer the above code for demo.
What I need to do is, I want to disable the child div scrollbar but not the functionality of child div scrolling. so when the parent scrollbar is moved, the child div scrolling activity will take place, once the child div is scrolled completely, second child div scrolling will start and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Added below style also -

```
.clsText{
  ...
 padding-right: 20px;
 margin-right: -20px;
}

#answerform{
  ....

    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

---

```css
#answerform
{
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    background: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.clsHeader
{
height:30px;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;    
  position: relative;
}
.clsText
{
height:250px;
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;   
 overflow-y: scroll; 
  position: relative;
padding-right: 20px;
margin-right: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='answerform'>
    <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
        <div class="clsText">
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        badger<br />badger<br />badger<br />
        </div>
    <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
        <div class="clsText">
        badger
        </div>
    <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
        <div class="clsText">
        badger
        </div>
    <div class="clsHeader">Header</div>
        <div class="clsText">
        badger
        </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: hey, but the 1st div slider is not working, the slider here is working only for parent div, I need is the single slider should scroll 1st div, after completion of 1st div scroll should move to second div scrolling, and so on

Comment: cant find a solution for scrolling both outer and inner by dragging the scrollbar..  this will work for scrolling using mouse scroll..

Answer (score 0):

For `.clsText`, change the `overflow-y: scroll;` to `overflow-y: auto;`